# Uncaught ReferenceError: (field name) is not defined when setting value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to set the value of a textbox when I load a page. I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined". Also tried the JQuery way that I mention in the comment and that just gets ignored. Also played around with having the value attribute in there for the input and that didn't help.

Been looking around online but not seeing anything wrong with what I'm doing. It seems like the textbox doesn't exist yet when the code runs but that shouldn't be. I can also read from the textbox with a button click fine.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
test.value = "5";  //also tried $( "#test").val("5");
});
</script>
```

Comment: That should work just fine, both of them actually, so you must be doing something else wrong, and as both are in the DOM ready handler, I'm guessing you didn't properly include jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p94JY/

Comment: I would think jQuery would be properly included if he is getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined", because that would indicate that the $(document).ready function is firing.

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing an object `test` which was never defined. You can fix it with:

```
$("#test").val("5");
```

You may also want to use vanilla javascript for something simple like this.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("test");
  el.value = "5";
});
```

Comment: Tried both... no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Your second try is working fine

```
$("#test").val(5)
```

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/vDC6X/

Comment: Both of them actually work fine for me in jsfiddle, but not in my page. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the right ID of the element.
You say textbox... does the textbox id render as test ?
Take a look at the page source of the rendered page.

Comment: Using the right ID. Everything looks correct when I look at the source.

Answer (score -1):

You have not imported jquery min.js

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```